# mongodb - how it processes $lt on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where one of the fields is a subdocument.  I am confused how mongodb supports the $lt, $gt query operators on the complete subdocument.
sample:

```
db.test.insert({a:1, subdocA:{x:4, y:7, z:10}, b:10})
db.test.insert({a:9, subdocA:{x:2, y:70, z:5}, b:9})
db.test.insert({a:4, subdocA:{x:8, y:2, z:45}, b:19})
```

In the above collection, I see that mongodb supports a query like:

```
db.test.find({subdocA:{$lt:{x:6, y:5, z:25}})
```

In fact it also supports similar queries with $gt operator.  It also supports sort({subdocA:1}) on the query.
I would like to know the "logic" it uses to compare the subdocuments and thereby process the $lt, $gt operators.

I see mongodb documentation about how exact matches are processed with subdocuments. But I don't see any documentation on how $lt, $gt are handled with subdocuments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the operator for each field, naming the field with a dot (`.`) to reach inside the embeeded document. [The documentation about `$gt` hints at this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/).

So to query a subdocument on `z` lower than 20, you actually search for `subdocA.z` being lower than 20, like this :

```
> db.test.find({'subdocA.z':{$lt:20}}, {_id:0})
{ "a" : 1, "subdocA" : { "x" : 4, "y" : 7, "z" : 10 }, "b" : 10 }
{ "a" : 9, "subdocA" : { "x" : 2, "y" : 70, "z" : 5 }, "b" : 9 }
```

You can add other criteria in the same way, here with `subdocA.x` lower than 3 :

```
> db.test.find({'subdocA.z':{$lt:20}, 'subdocA.x':{$lt:3}}, {_id:0})
{ "a" : 9, "subdocA" : { "x" : 2, "y" : 70, "z" : 5 }, "b" : 9 }
```

Finally, you can mix and match fields from the "base" document :

```
> db.test.find({'subdocA.z':{$lt:20}, 'a':{$gt:3}}, {_id:0})
{ "a" : 9, "subdocA" : { "x" : 2, "y" : 70, "z" : 5 }, "b" : 9 }
```

Comment: i got the same results (as you) for my mongodb query.  To me, it seems that mongodb ignores the values on 'y' and 'z'.  It only uses value of 'x' to do the comparison. I also tried a query based only on 'z': db.test.find({subdocA:{$lt:{z:3}}}, {_id:0}).  And that returned all the documents (I would have thought it should return none as all values of z are greater than 3).  I am wondering whether the behaviour is by design at all.

Comment: I don't know if it by design, but I updated my answer with the proper, explicit way to query subdocuments, one field at a time. +Welcome to StackOverflow !