# Query MongoDB subfield query select/find? not sure what to do

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "----number-----" ),
  "interaction" : { "author" : { "link" : "------",
      "avatar" : "----link---",
      "name" : "-----name----",
      "id" : "12345678" },
```

How do I query mongodb to give me a list of id's from this sort of field? If you know, I also need to group them descending by count. Is there an equivalent of group by as in sql?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what were you expecting ? Query is [`find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), sorting is [`sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/). +Welcome to StackOverflow !

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to specify the subgroups

Comment: Use the `.` operator. `db.test.find({'interaction.author':'Joe'})`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19569442/591064

Comment: for some reason db.test.find({'interaction.author'}) didn't work when i do db.test.distinct({'interaction.author'}) it works

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

The query you're looking for should be like this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$iteraction.id', hits: {$sum: 1}}}, {$sort: {hits: -1}}])
```